# Xenserver Java API start VM

Tags: java, xen

I am using XenServer 6.5

In Java, I use SDK library

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.vcc.thirdparty</groupId>
    <artifactId>xen-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.0-3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then I create my instance with a template.

```
VM template = VM.getByNameLabel(connection, templateName).iterator()
                .next();
VM vm = template.createClone(connection, instanceName);
vm.setIsATemplate(connection, false);
vm.removeFromOtherConfig(connection, "disks");
vm.setNameLabel(connection, instanceName);
vm.setMemoryStaticMin(connection, new Long(256));
vm.setMemoryDynamicMin(connection, new Long(256));
vm.setMemoryDynamicMax(connection, new Long(256));
vm.setMemoryStaticMax(connection, new Long(256));
vm.setVCPUsAtStartup(connection, new Long(1));
```

After I create an instance, I try to start it.

```
VM vm = VM.getByNameLabel(connection, name).iterator().next();
vm.start(connection, false, false);
System.out.println(vm.getPowerState(connection));
```

But it returns

```
The server failed to handle your request, due to an internal error.  The given message may give details useful for debugging the problem.
    at com.xensource.xenapi.Types.checkResponse(Types.java:1609)
    at com.xensource.xenapi.Connection.dispatch(Connection.java:395)
    at com.xensource.xenapi.VM.start(VM.java:3118)
    at com.apo.region.vm.XenConnectionsManager.startVM(XenConnectionsManager.java:79)
    at com.apo.region.controller.VMController.list(VMController.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I searched on the Internet, and found that
the create function doesn't have two boolean parameters for:

```
vm.start(connection);
```

But I try different version of Maven with:

```
vm.start(connection, false, false);
```

And the error message doesn't have much information. Did I miss any steps?

Answer (score 0):

I am really sorry to answer so late, but I just saw yesterday the question and I wished to test something before answer you.
About the memory issue, any setting of memory is in bytes, due this, the parameter is long (for allow huge memory configurations).You set your new VM to 512 bytes only in both memories, static and dynamic, less than Spectrum!!
With that though in mind, my supposition is your memory limits are too low because the **GUEST OS** has memory restriction (specially Windows). In this [blog](http://baudlabs.com/minimum-and-maximum-memory-ram-requirements-for-current-microsoft-windows-operating-systems-os-hyper-v-dynamic-memory-configuration-guide/) you can see the minimum/maximum memory for guest OS related to other hypervisor (however I think is equal in Xenserver).
Anyway, this snippet is working for me using the same maven dependency, and same xenserver - *6.5* - as you.
For more information about `vm.start(con,false,false)` you can download [Xenserver 6.5 SDK](http://downloadns.citrix.com.edgesuite.net/10342/XenServer-6.5.0-SP1-SDK.zip) and see the javadoc related to VM. The second parameter is to allow start in pause mode and the third one is to force the start operation.

```
       try
       {
            Connection con = new Connection(new URL(url));
            Session.loginWithPassword(con, user, pass);
            String templateName = "template-test";
            String instanceName = "testVM";
            VM template = VM.getByNameLabel(con, templateName).iterator().next();
            VM vm = template.createClone(con, instanceName);
            vm.setNameLabel(con, instanceName);
            //This numbers are upper than required minimum for Windows 7
            //My Guest OS
            vm.setMemoryStaticMin(connection, 1073741824L);
            vm.setMemoryDynamicMin(connection, 4294967296L);
            vm.setMemoryDynamicMax(connection, 1073741824L);            
            vm.setMemoryStaticMax(connection, 4294967296L);
            vm.setVCPUsAtStartup(con, 1L);
            vm.provision(con);
            VM vm2 = VM.getByNameLabel(con, instanceName).iterator().next();
            vm2.start(con, false, false);
            System.out.println(vm2.getPowerState(con));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```